# process geojson and find a given point contains within polygon

Tags: java, geojson

I have a requirement to process geojson file (it has multiple polygons) and find a given point (longitude and latitude) contains with in polygon. I am looking for a java solution. Can you please recommend possible solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When one needs a geometry library for Java [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) should be mentioned at first. And of course [Java-GeoJSon](https://github.com/mapfish/java-geojson) to load the data. The latter library is built upon JTS, so you even don't need any special adapters between two libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more functionality than what JTS offers, you should check out [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/).

It provides the ability to read and write most major cartographic formats, supports map projections and coordinate transformations, and is a much more full featured GIS suite.

JTS is strictly geometry -- it deals with 2d shapes with no units attached.